# VueJS v-if json value from json is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

my question is how can I show "show text" in the layout when "more": true is set in my JSON

**My Layout:**

```html
<b-row v-for="?" v-if="?">
    <b-col>
        show text
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

**My JSON:**

```json
{
  "array": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "more": false
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "more": true
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    n: 0,
    array: json
  }
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED IT => v-if="array[0].more"

Comment: Something like `v-for="foo in array" v-if="foo.more"` should do it, I think? If that doesn't work, try the `v-if` on the `<b-col>`.

Comment: @ceejayoz No :(

Comment: use a computed prop instead

Comment: @ceejayoz looks like it should be `v-for="foo in array.array"`. It's an odd structure

Comment: @Phil is there a better way?

Comment: I'd probably go with `array: json.array` in your `data` function, just to eliminate the `array.array` duplication

Comment: @Phil yeah that`s better, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've never been a fan of conditional rendering in a loop.

My preference is to use a computed property that returns a filtered set of your iterable object. For example

```js
computed: {
  more () {
    return this.array.array.filter(({ more }) => more)
  }
}
```

then in your template

```html
<b-row v-for="item in more">
  <b-col>
    show text
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<b-row v-for="el of array.array" v-if="el.more">
    <b-col>
        show text
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

In your json, you have your array in the property `array`. Your vue component set the data of the json in the property `array`. This means the array is accessible in `array.array`.

Comment: v-for="array of/in array.array" v-if="array. more" doesn't work. it shows the row both when it`s true and false.